# Python: set varaibles in array

Tags: python

Is it possible to set piece array as [x , y] variable. For example, piece [ [x1,y1],[x2,y2],....]

Below is my code:

```
piece = [[387,500] , [247,499] , [120,496] , [533,488] , [191,432] , [464,432],[328,426] , [50,426]]

if (292<x<350) and (390<y<450) in piece:
    print("do something")
```

Comment: *Is it possible...?*  Have you *tried* it?

Comment: There are three different ways to interpret this: print "do something" 1) each time the condition is true, 2) if the condition is true for *all* pairs or 3) if the condition is true for *any* pair.

Answer (score 2):

```
for x, y in piece:
    if (292<x<350) and (390<y<450):
        print("do something")
```